# Angular JS orderBy attribute reserve table

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a table which can be reverse-ordered.
Somehow, with particular `<th>` tags, **Value (bit)** and **Value (byte)** it isn't reversed.

My AngualrJS code:

```
function DataCTRL($scope){
        $scope.datas = [
          {"name": "Char", "valueBit": 8, "valueByted": 1, "range": "0 to 255 or -128 to 127", "programmingLanguage": "C"},
        {"name": "Unsigned Char", "valueBit": 8, "valueByte": 1, "range": "0 to 255", "programmingLanguage": "C"},
        {"name": "Signed Char", "valueBit": 8, "valueByte": 1, "range": "-128 to 127", "programmingLanguage": "C"},
        {"name": "Int", "valueBit": 4 , "valueByte": 32, "range": "-32,768 to 32,767 OR -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647", "programmingLanguage": "C"}
        ];
        $scope.sortField = '';
        $scope.reverse = true;
      }
```

Here's my [`DEMO`](http://jsbin.com/civotafe/1/edit).

I tried remove the quotation marks (which declare of strings) and keep the numbers only, but nothing has changed.
I even tried use another `$scope.secreverse` but the result wasn't different.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `sortField = 'value(bit)'` in ngClick, it should be `sortField = 'valueBit'` to match the property name in the object. Same thing for `value(byte)`...

```
<th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'valueBit'; reverse = !reverse">Value (bit)</a></th>
<th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'valueByte'; reverse = !reverse">Value (byte)</a></th>
```

[**JsBin**](http://jsbin.com/civotafe/2/edit?html,js,output)